# Too many results in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fetching some data from our database in MSSQL. Out of this data I want to determine who created the client entry and who took the first payment from this client.

There can be many payment entries for a client on a single booking/enquiry and at the moment, my query shows results for each payment. How can I limit the output to only show the first payment entry?

My query:

```
SELECT 
 c.FirstName,
 c.LastName,
 c.PostalCode,
 o.OriginOfEnquiry,
 s.SuperOriginName,
 c.DateOfCreation,
 DATEDIFF(day, c.DateOfCreation, p.DateOfCreation) AS DaysToPayment,
 pc.PackageName,
 CONCAT(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) AS CreateUser,
 (SELECT CONCAT(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName)  
   WHERE u.UserID = p.UserID ) AS PaymentUser

FROM tblBookings b

INNER JOIN tblPayments p
 ON b.BookingID = p.BookingID
INNER JOIN tblEnquiries e
 ON e.EnquiryID = b.EnquiryID
INNER JOIN tblCustomers c
 ON c.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
INNER JOIN tblOrigins o
 ON o.OriginID = e.OriginID
INNER JOIN tblSuperOrigins s
 ON s.SuperOriginID = o.SuperOriginID
INNER JOIN tblBookingPackages bp
 ON bp.bookingID = p.BookingID
INNER JOIN tblPackages pc
 ON pc.PackageID = bp.packageID
INNER JOIN tblUsers u
 ON u.UserID = c.UserID

WHERE c.DateOfCreation >= '2016-06-01' AND c.DateOfCreation < '2016-06-30'
AND p.PaymentStatusID IN (1,2)
AND e.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
AND p.DeleteMark != 1
AND c.DeleteMark != 1
AND b.DeleteMark != 1
;
```

I tried adding a "TOP 1" to the nested select statement for PaymentUser, but it made no difference.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: you can use `cross apply` with `top 1`: `FROM tblBookings b cross apply (select top 1 * from tblPayments p where b.BookingID = p.BookingID) as p`

Comment: Here's another good tool to use when asking a question that includes several tables. http://sqlfiddle.com/.  Without knowing your schema and data, put the `TOP 1` in the initial select and order the whole query by `c.DateOfCreation`.

Comment: Tedo, that worked for me . Please add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it

Comment: please paste what is the ouput you are getting and what is the expected result from your query

Comment: @Stephen, posted. you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `cross apply` with `top 1`:

`FROM tblBookings b 
cross apply 
(select top 1 * from tblPayments p where b.BookingID = p.BookingID) as p`

Comment: @stephen -- if you need the "first" payment, that's not the same as the "top 1" payment in this answer.  FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of table `tblPayments` specify sub-query like this:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 BookingID, UserID, DateOfCreation
FROM tblPayments
WHERE DeleteMark != 1
AND PaymentStatusID IN (1,2)
ORDER BY DateOfCreation) as p
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming that `tblPayments` has a primary key column `ID`. If it is true, you can use this statment:

```
FROM tblBookings b

INNER JOIN tblPayments p ON p.ID = (
  SELECT TOP 1 ID
  FROM tblPayments
  WHERE BookingID = b.BookingID
    AND DeleteMark != 1
    AND PaymentStatusID IN (1,2) 
  ORDER BY DateOfCreation)
```

Comment: i think this code will still cause duplication. problem is in the very first join you have.

Comment: I'm not agree with you. Result of first JOIN limited by PK.